# Incorrect path in nested folders

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

In the `A.js` file, I am trying to import the 'B' class, which is in the B.js file. I'm leaving the folder 3 `../`, from the folder 2 `../`, from the folder 1 `../`, I'm going to `folder 4`, then to `folder 5` and the `file B.js`. Incorrect path error

```
app
    folder 1
        folder 2
            folder 3 
                file A.js    //import B from '../../../folder 4/folder 5/file B
    folder 4
        folder 5
            file B.js
```

Comment: Can you add the links, where those two files are located, please?

Comment: what URL _does_ it take you to, instead? If you check that, it'll probably give you a clue about how you need to amend it.

Comment: What is the exact error? Your path looks correct to me.

Comment: @ADyson I do not have any hints. Should I install any packages in visual studio code?